# Commutativity of Abelian schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

$S$ is a scheme, by an Abelian scheme over $S$ I mean a group scheme $X/S$ such that the structure morphism $X \rightarrow S$ is proper, flat and finite presentation. How to prove that $X$ is commutative?

My question is, given two $S$-morphism $f,g :Y \rightarrow Z$ between two $S$-schemes with $f_s=g_s, \forall s \in S$ (base change from $S$ to the residue field $k(s)$), under which assumption can we conclude $f=g$?

If this is not true in the proper and flat setting, how to prove that $X$ is commutative?

Comment: Have you done this when $S$ is a point?

Comment: As stated this is not true, you might want to impose connectedness of the fibers of $X \to S$.

Comment: If I remember well this is proved (with the right hypothesis, like Johann remarks) in Chapter 6 in GIT by Mumford.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first result of chapter 6 of Mumford's Geometric invariant theory, at least in the case that $S$ is locally Noetherian (and one can reduce to this case by standard limit arguments). It is indeed sufficient to ask for connected fibers (as Johann mentions), but in fact we can get away with less.

Let $f:Y \to Z$ be a morphism of (locally) finite type schemes over a connected locally Noetherian scheme $S$, with $Z$ is separated and $Y$ is proper and flat. Suppose that there is a point $s \in S$ such that $f(Y_s)$ is a point (set theoretically) and suppose that for all $s' \in S$ we have $h^0(X_{s'})=1$. Then there is a section $\eta:S \to Z$ such that $f$ factors over $\eta$. See [here](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/deformations-of-abelian-varieties-ii-rigidity/#more-3484) for a nice explanation of the proof.

One can apply this theorem to show that for an abelian scheme $A/S$, the map $(-1):A \to A$ is a group homomorphism, which implies that $A$ is a commutative group scheme. Let me point out that an abelian scheme is usually defined to be a proper ***smooth*** group scheme with **connected** (geometric) fibers, so your definition is definitely nonstandard.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't read that book and I come across a note about abelian schemes which says that many results of abelian varieties can be generalized by passing to the fibers. But I do not know how to prove the commutativity so I ask this question.

Comment: This particular result can be used to lift many results about abelian varieties to abelian schemes (for example the theorem of the square, using representability of the picard scheme by a separated locally of finite type group scheme)